# UITextView is nil when attempting to set for popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two View Controllers: `SavePopOverVC` and `MainVC`. I also have a nib file called `SavePopOver`. `SavePopOver` has three items, a `UIButton`, a `UIImage` and a `UITextView`. The image and text view have outlets to `property` fields in `SavePopOverVC` called captionImage and captionTextView respectively. The button has an outlet to an `IBAction` in `SavePopOverVC`.

In `MainVC.m` I have the following two lines in my class extension.

```
SavePopOverVC *spvc;
UIPopoverController *popover;
```

In my `viewDidLoad` of the same file I have the following lines relating to my popover.

```
spvc = [[SavePopOverVC alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"SavePopOver" bundle:nil];
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:spvc];
```

In my function that displays my popover, also in `MainVC.m`, I have the following lines.

```
[popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600,200)];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:_header.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirection:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[((SavePopOverVC *)popover.contentViewController).captionTextView setText:@"Some text here"];
```

However, `captionTextView` is nil when I make the `setText:` call. The app doesn't crash but the text isn't set. After the popover is displayed and I click on the `UIButton` to save the string typed in `captionTextView` I get the string just fine. So, I know the two are ultimately linked correctly, but how can I set `captionTextView` from when I display the popover?

If it is worth noting, I'm developing solely for iPad with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely `nil` because its view isn't loaded at the time you set the text. Unlike most other modern languages, in Objective-C calling a method on a `nil` object doesn't cause an exception, it just does nothing.

To solve this, you can create a custom `NSString` property in your `SavePopOverVC`, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *caption;
```

Before you call `presentPopoverFromRect:`, assign a value to this property. Inside `SavePopOverVC`, override `viewDidLoad` and set the `captionTextView.text = self.caption;`

There might be people who disagree with me, but I don't recommend exposing UI controls as properties in a view controller. This behaviour is one of the reasons for that.

Comment: But won't that lead to memory leaks? I plan on calling this popover quite a bit and once I implement setting the image in the popover I fear any leaks could add up fast.

Comment: What makes you think that would cause any memory leaks?